# Validate the drop down boxes with same "id"

Tags: java, selenium

I have a problem here , I m trying to automate the dropdown boxes with same "id" . Ther are three such Dropdown boxes . I have to select one option under each . Help ? 
Website : http://bookboon.com/en/basics-of-accounting-information-processing-ebook#download

```
package flow;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class bookboon {
    static WebDriver d  ;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\User_2\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        d = new ChromeDriver();
        d.get("http://bookboon.com/en/accounting-ebooks");
        List<WebElement> downlinks = d.findElements(By.className("pdf"));
        for(int i=1;i<=downlinks.size();i++) {
            downlinks.get(i).click();
            d.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("asd@ymail.com");
            d.findElement(By.id("undefined_flexselect")).sendKeys("Studying");
            d.findElement(By.id("undefined_flexselect")).sendKeys("Engineer/Science MSc");
            d.findElement(By.id("undefined_flexselect")).sendKeys("All India Institute of Medical Sciences (AIIMS), Delhi");
            //d.navigate().back();
            //downlinks = d.findElements(By.className("pdf"));
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried with Xpath . Couldn't get it done. Please help !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this..

```
d.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("asd@ymail.com");
WebElement fOne=d.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/article/div/section[1]/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/input"));
fOne.sendKeys("Studying");
fOne.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
Sleeper.sleepTightInSeconds(2);
WebElement fTwo=d.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/article/div/section[1]/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/input"));
fTwo.sendKeys("Engineer/Science MSc");
fTwo.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
Sleeper.sleepTightInSeconds(2);
WebElement fThree=d.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/article/div/section[1]/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/input"));
fThree.sendKeys("All India Institute of Medical Sciences (AIIMS), Delhi");
fThree.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```

Comment: It is works perfectly.. then why the people downvoted my answer I don't know

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following the select the 'nth' xpath value.

```
"(//elementType[@id='undefined_flexselect'])[n]"
```

Replace n in the brackets with the number of the record you would like to select.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine two properties to identify an element:

```
d.findElement(By.xpath(".//select[@name='answers' and @data-placeholder='Studying or working?']")).sendKeys("Studying");
```

Or take all of them and after that take each one:

```
List<WebElement> a = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//select[@name='answers']"));
a.get(0).sendKeys("Studying");
```